# dwg in QGIS - which CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dwg

I got a dwg-file which I imported in QGIS, it is displayed allright. 
There was a prj-file which stated that that the CRS should be EPSG 31258, which I used for importing the file. However it does no match at all, it it isn't even in the area of OSM.

I checked the file in TrueView, there it shows "WCS".
There coordinates displayed in Qgis and TrueView are about: 89708467,340439859.
All common CRSs (at least the one I  know) for the areas were checked.

Is there a way to determine or set the correct CRS?

Comment: UTM-based CRS usually have up to 6 digits, your WCS-values are way larger which doesn't make sense. AutoCAD projects sometimes have an additional false easting of 32 or 33 million (in Germany) in order to indicate which UTM-zone is being use. This could account for your second value, but does not explain the about 90 million of your first value.

Comment: thanks! the utm zone would be not common for the dataset, but i checked UTMs: not result.

Comment: What is the approximate size of 1 unit of your mystery coordinate system in your drawing? If it appears to be meters, then maybe an offset has been applied, and could possibly be found with reference points in your drawing. If it's not close to any known unit, then perhaps you are facing a completely different unit and/or coordinate system altogether.

Comment: Measure does not work!? Didn't try this. Probably there there is no spatial information, dispite the prj-file? Asked to get a new file with proper CRS. I will try to provide a solution... Thanks